# How to use a specific function in the telegram API in Python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using Python3+ and working with the Telethon Library (https://docs.telethon.dev/)

I need to programmatically accept every user's join request in a channel.
I found this "api call (?)": https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.hideAllChatJoinRequests

**That's exactly what i need. But i have no idea how to use it**.

For exemple, to get all the user's dialogs, i would do this:

*Find the correct api call in telethon library then figure things out from it*. (https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.get_dialogs)

I can't find anything about the "hideAllChatJoinRequests" in the telethon library, so i'm a bit lost on how to proceed from here.

Thanks in advance !